# Привязка переменной к textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, binding, xaml

Изучаю *WPF* и пытаюсь разобраться с привязками. Хочу привязать переменную `t` типа `String`, объявленную  в классе `MainWindow`, к `textbox`.

Чтобы при изменении `t` изменялась бы и строка, отображаемая в `textbox`, а при изменении текста в `textbox` он бы записывался в переменную `t`.

*C#*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Media;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string t = "dfs";
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            box.Text = t;
        }
    }
}
```

*XAML*:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="box" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="238,251,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Что нужно добавить в код, чтобы привязка заработала?

Answer (score 3):

1. Объявите `t` как `DependencyProperty`.
2. Привяжите значение через `Binding`.
3. Укажите в свойствах `Binding`'а `Mode=TwoWay`, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.
4. Строка `box.Text = t;` больше не нужна.

Должно работать.

Comment: А как объявить t как DependencyProperty? Может быть можете скинуть код? Как я понял код от Макс Жуков не совсем правелен...

Comment: Пытался сделать как Вы написали, но не работает. Видимо я как то не так определяю DependencyProperty Код С#:

  public static readonly DependencyProperty tProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("t", typeof(string), typeof(TextBox));

        public string t
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(tProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(tProperty, value);
            }
        }
вот как подключаю в XAML:
<TextBox  Text="{Binding Path=t, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

Comment: Не-не, в объявлении `tProperty` надо так:

    public static readonly DependencyProperty tProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("t", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow));

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt: Затем, вы должны указать правильный `DataContext`. `Binding` идёт к property `t` из текущего `DataContext`. Проще всего сделать так:

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

Ну или куча других методов.

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало.

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Ещё вазник вопрос. А как всё это организовать, если нужно привязать не переменную, а поле объекта? Т.е. если у меня обявлен отдельно класс, внутри которого есть поле "t" и я создаю объект этого класса в MainWindow, можно ли как то поле этого объекта привязать к textbox?

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt: Не-а, поле нельзя. Даже просто свойство сработает лишь частично: значение обновится только один раз.

Сорри.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте DependencyProperty:

В code-behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(TextBox),
            new System.Windows.PropertyMetadata(PropertyChanged));

public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

private static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox control = depObj as TextControl;
            if (e.Property == TextProperty)
            {
                control.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
                return;
            }
         }
```

В разметке:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextProperty}"/>
```

Мб пример не совсем точный, навскидку с мобильника писал, но суть изложил.

Comment: А зачем `PropertyChanged`? Просто привяжитесь как `TwoWay`.

Comment: Да чего действительно не понятно, зачем тогда писать весь это Binding, если всё равно в итоге пишем PropertyChanged, может можно как то без PropertyChanged? Может быть кто нибудь может скинуть простой код?